# Criteria Morphia MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I have a collection like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53f34ef8ec10d6fa97dcc34b"
    },

    "editions": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            ...
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            ...
        },
    ...
   ]
}
```

I want filter results of my query by some number.

I tried

```
criterias.add(query.criteria("editions.number").equal(paramNumber));
```

And

```
query.filter("editions.number =", paramNumber)
```

However I just received all collection, when I pass paramNumber equals 2. What I want is receive the following result:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53f34ef8ec10d6fa97dcc34b"
    },

    "editions": [

        {
            "number": 2,
            ...
        }
   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't receive partial arrays like that.  You'll get back with the full document/object or just the fields you've specified in a [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: Thx @evanchooly, as far as I researched there are a couple of features that Morphia don't support yet, aggregation is one of them. I solve this problem without mongodb query support

Comment: Morphia does, in fact, support aggregations.  I wrote the code not quite a year ago.  It's in the 0.108 release.

Comment: Thx @evanchooly In my researches I just saw people asking about this featuring, I didn't realise that this feature is already implemented. I am using that Morphia version in my project.